# How to deal with the ECC support feature in NVIDIA graphics cards

Tags: cuda, nvidia

the server have setup two `NVIDIA K20m` cards, but with `ECC` enabled. I have observed that the `Volatile GPU-Utilization` is high using the `nvidia-smi -a` command, even through no computing task is running in the card. The `K20m` is just used for computing. I have searched in `Google`, and checked the following links: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/539632/k20-with-high-utilization-but-no-compute-processes-/ and https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/464744/how-to-disable-enable-ecc-on-c2050-/

It seems the `ECC` is always a bad feature, so it is always set to be `disabled`. So what's the true  meaning with the `ECC`? I'm just a commont user of that server, so I don't have the right to use the command `nvidia-smi -e 0` to set `ECC` to be disabled. Is it possible for common user to set the `ECC` to be disabled?

What are the effects when we turn off the `ECC`? When should we turn it on? and when off?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The GPU utilization may become non-zero when running `nvidia-smi` even when no other compute tasks are running.  This has no connection to ECC.

> So what's the true meaning with the ECC?

ECC is [Error Correcting Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory).   It is not unique to GPUs.  On GPUs,  it is a feature that uses extra memory bits to store error information, so that if an error (of particular severity) occurs in the memory subsystem it can either be detected and reported, or detected and corrected.

> Is it possible for common user to set the ECC to be disabled?

Disabling ECC requires root privilege on linux.

> What are the effects when we turn off the ECC?

The available bandwidth as well as memory size available to your GPU application may/will be increased.  If you turn off ECC and a memory subsystem error occurs, you'll receive no explicit notification.  The error could have any range of effects from no effect at all, to a complete application crash, depending on in what context the error occurred.

> When should we turn it on? and when off?

Turn it on when you want protection from memory corruption errors.  Turn it off if you want maximum performance (e.g. for benchmarking) or you believe that your application can tolerate memory errors (e.g. you check the validity of results and you don't mind re-running an application that failed for some reason.)

Note that some newer GPUs with HBM (HBM2) memory may have [somewhat different characteristics](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pascal-tuning-guide/index.html#hbm2).  Because of the design of HBM2 memory, enabling ECC generally results in little or no performance loss (bandwidth) and no reduction in memory size.  For GPUs with HBM2 memory, the general recommendation is to leave the ECC on all the time.

Comment: Thank you, sir. In fact, I just found that if the valatile GPU-utilization is high, the response of the system is very slow. And when I submitt a job into the cluster, the scheduler allocate the job into the computing node with GPUs, then the process also starts slow. So I'm wondering if any configuration is wrong. The `SDK` is `CUDA-6.0` and the driver is that along with it.

Comment: I have tested at those computing nodes with the GPUs, and found that some machines have slow responses to the request of GPU usage, but the others are OK. So I want to figure out what the problems are. And at one node, the `lspci` shows two `K20m` GPUs have setuped, but when I use the `nvidia-smi`, it says it couldn't find them and output 'Unable to determine the device handle for GPU 0000:81:00.0'. I think I also should ask the manager of the cluster for help. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to disable ECC without having a GPU card? Ie I am building an image on a machine without a GPU but when I use the image, the machine will have a GPU and I would like ECC to be disabled at that point. Right now I can't do it at boot time since I then have to reboot the GPU box.

Comment: Turning ECC on and off must be done programmatically.  Normally this means the GPU must be present, and you would use the `nvidia-smi` command line tool to enable or disable it on the GPU in question.  You may be able to perform a similar function using the NVML library, I haven't researched this thoroughly.  If that is the case, then it would allow you to compile a program and use NVML to turn ECC on and off.  However, turning ECC on and off requires a reboot, after the program/change is made.

Comment: Hi @RobertCrovella, I have another problem: are there any differences between 2-way SLI with 16x/16x and 2-way SLI with 8x/8x for deep learning applications? In the second mode, the throughput of the GPU are limited by the bandwidth, is it right? Thanks.

Comment: SLI has nothing to do with CUDA or deep learning, and it's generally recommended that you disable SLI on CUDA gpus.